# kaminari pagination error undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

this is my post_controller

```
def index
@posts = Post.all.page(params[:page]).per(2)


respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @posts }
end
 end
```

this is /views/posts/index

```
<%= paginate @posts %>
```

and i recive:

NoMethodError in PostsController#index

undefined method `page' for #

---

I saw many themes with the same error and solution:

```
Kaminari.paginate_array(my_array_object).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

but where should i put this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it in your controller

```
@posts = Kaminari.paginate_array(my_array_object).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

But you also could do this:

```
@posts = Post.page(params[:page]).per(2)
```

Comment: I get an undefined method "paginate_array" for Kaminari:module how to solve this?